# How can I compare a boolean to an array? - Swift

Tags: swift

I have this:

```
if sender.tag == 1 || sender.tag == 2 || sender.tag == 3 || sender.tag == 4 || sender.tag == 5 || sender.tag == 6 || sender.tag == 7 || sender.tag == 8 || sender.tag == 9 || sender.tag == 10 {
```

Is there anyway to minimize this some similar to this:

```
if sender.tag == [1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 ||  7 || 8 || 9 || 10] {
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
if (1...10).contains(sender.tag)
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
if 1 <= sender.tag && sender.tag <= 10 {
```

This checks if `sender.tag` is between 1 and 10 inclusive.

Comment: Why would someone down vote a perfectly legitimate way to check a value? Just because it isn't some fancy "Swifty" way doesn't make it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set or range:

```
let tagsSet: Set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

if tagsSet.contains(sender.tag)
```